# convert a list [['a'], ['b']] to ['a','b']

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

In `python 3`, how can I convert a list `[['a'], ['b']]` to `['a','b']` ?

I am a beginner programmer and have not been able to solve this problem myself.

Comment: Apart from it being a duplicate, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = [['a'],['b']]

a = [item for list in a for item in list]
print a
>>>['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
[i[0] for i in [['a'], ['b']]
>>> ['a','b']
```

Comment: What about 2 elements sublist?

Comment: this won't work for `[['a','b'],['c','d']]`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary working of this line depends on a question that was asked.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), specifically [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) (this is much better than devising your own way of doing it):

```
>>> l = [['a'], ['b']]
>>> print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)))
['a', 'b']
```

---

This is faster than the pure list-comprehension solution as well:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7], [8,9]]*99' '[item for sublist in l for item in sublist]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 53.9 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7], [8,9]]*99' 'list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.5 usec per loop
```

(Tests adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) question)

Comment: @RohitJain That is also possible, but probably not as efficient as `itertools`.

Comment: Hmm. Well, No idea about performance. So, I'll take your point.

Comment: @RohitJain `itertools.chain()` should be preferred over `sum()`,coz for e.g `sum()` will not work for list of tuples.even documentation says that http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum, we should prefer `chain()`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary.. Thanks for clarifying. That is valuable.